# Easily upgrade Requests's vendored version of urllib3?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

Python's Requests library [bundles the `chardet` and `urllib3` packages](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tree/master/requests/packages).

This can mean that the bundled version will have bugs. I am wondering if there is a clean or easy way to get Requests to use a different version of urllib3. For example, could I `pip install requests urllib3` and then have requests use that version automatically?

I know that Requests [automatically uses `certifi`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/e23bf10cf4ecc62f6c3dd6284043516fb833d9ce/docs/user/advanced.rst#ca-certificates) instead of its bundled certificate, if `certifi` is installed, but I couldn't find documentation like this for `urllib3`.

Otherwise the options I see are:

1. Get requests to merge the newest version of urllib3,
2. Fork my own version of requests and use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options you've outlined are correct as of today.

There has been some talk of having a Requests setting which uses the system version of urllib3, but I don't believe it has been implemented. Some Linux distributions' packaging actually patches Requests to use the system version of urllib3 (and pin it accordingly), so it's not an uncommon request.

As for using certifi with urllib3, [it's outlined in the Security section](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#using-certifi-with-urllib3) of the documentation. Here's the main piece:

```
import urllib3
import certifi

http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', # Force certificate check.
    ca_certs=certifi.where(),  # Path to the Certifi bundle.
)

# You're ready to make verified HTTPS requests.
try:
    r = http.request('GET', 'https://example.com/')
except urllib3.exceptions.SSLError as e:
    # Handle incorrect certificate error.
    ...
```

Comment: Can you point me to the discussions around a Requests setting using the system version of urllib3? For future reference, RHEL is an example of linking the bundled urllib3 and chardet to system versions.

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues?q=vendored will get you several related discussions, https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1812 and https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1811 for example. I can't find the specific comment which proposed supporting both scenarios.